# Как сменить стандартную оболочку терминала в fedora 22?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora

Сразу скажу, что эта команда не подходит `update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` она для debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chsh --help
```

Если ввести `chsh -l`, то терминал выдаст весь список доступных оболочек.

Comment: ответ совершенно про другое. исправьте уж тогда, пожалуйста, вопрос, чтобы он имел хоть какое-то отношение к ответу.

Comment: Вопрос про эмулятор терминала, ответ про оболочки, ерунда какая-то.

Comment: Лично мне удалось с помощью этой команды сменить эмулятор терминала. Если посмотрите в гугл по запросу "как сменить эмулятор терминала linux" и "как сменить оболочку терминала linux" - то по последнему Вы не найдете вообще никакой инфы. Допускаю, что я использовал неправильную формулировку (и люди, которые отвечают по таким запросам тоже "как сменить эмулятор терминала linux"), однако, на других форумах, не буду указывать каких, дабы не сочли за рекламу, меня поняли и дали внятный ответ, без каких либо поправок. Я же просто разместил ответ в этой теме, если кому будет необходима данная инфа.

Comment: @ЮрийГлушенков Так отредактируйте вопрос, чтоб ответу соответствовал.